# Can't change JFrame dimensions when set visible

Tags: java, database, swing, jframe, preferredsize

I'm an SQL-beginner, I'm trying to write a simple application that allows me to manage my games library.
I tried doing various `SELECT` from the db and all works properly.
Now the problem: when I click on `btnAdd` I want to set my `addGame` frame visible.

I tried this:

```
addGame.setVisible(true);
```

but when I set it visible, [that's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnNuT.png) the result.

My Main Activity is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWN5L.png).

The Event bound to the button is:

```
private void btnAggiungiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    addGame.pack();
    //Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 100);
    //addGame.setPreferredSize(d);
    addGame.setVisible(true);
}
```

But with `addGame.pack();` it only fits horizontal dimension. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what is specifically wrong without more code, preferably a small compilable program, but in general you should

- make sure that your GUI uses layout managers sensibly and avoids use of null layout if at all possible.
- avoid calling `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)` if possible.
- pack your GUI's before displaying them by calling `pack()` on the top-level window prior to calling `setVisible(true)`
- let the GUI's components and layout managers size themselves.

Comment: The code I posted is what is inside the `btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`, I don't think you need other code.. But if you need it, I'll post it.
I tried doing `addGame.pack();` but it adjusts only the horizontal dimension.

Comment: @FedericoPepe: `"I don't think you need other code..."` -- this is a mighty presumptuous thing to say. I can tell you that if you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) you're almost guaranteed to get a better answer quicker. With snippets like you've posted, all you'll likely see are bad answers such as the `setSize(...)` suggestion that you received previously or vague general advice such as mine.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed presumptuous, it was not my intention. I'll post an sscce.

Comment: I edited the question, I really think that it'd be useless if I add more code, it is not related to what am I looking for..

Comment: @FedericoPepe: OK. Best of luck. Myself, I find I can help much better if I know and can see the cause of the problem. Hopefully someone else will be able to better help you without this information.

Comment: I really need help, if you want I post the code of all the frames.

Comment: @FedericoPepe: see edit to comment above. No, we don't want to see all the code since we're volunteers with limited time. Instead consider posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small program that has no code unrelated to the problem, that we can compile and run, and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the time I made you waste, I found the problem. I don't know when, but I changed the "Preferred size" of the `addGame` and I didn't notice it. However thanks a lot for the tips.